# how to pass the id value of the grid to a button?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I am trying to pass the idEvento2 value of my grid to my button with the function descargartodo so that all the documents with the same id can be downloaded when pressing the button
how could i do it?

html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="state$ | async as state">
  <lib-modal-container class="bootstrap-wrapper"
                       [modalTitle]="state.title"
                       [formType]="state.formType"
                       [loading]="state.loading"
                       (dismiss)="handleClose()">   
    <div class="m-r-12">
      <div class="fixed-bottom-buttons text-right">
        <button 
                matTooltip="descargar archivos"
                class="mini-icon-button"
                mat-flat-button
                color="primary"
                type="button"
                (click)="descargartodo()">
          <mat-icon> file_download</mat-icon>
          Decargar todo
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
      <lib-grid variant="list"
                emptyRowsMsg="No hay registros"
                [loading]="state.gridControlResumen.loading"
                [definition]="state.gridControlResumen.definition"
                [source]="state.gridControlResumen.source">   
        <ng-template libTemplate="tpl-accion"
                     let-data>
          <button matTooltip="Ver archivo"
                  class="mini-icon-button"
                  mat-icon-button
                  value="documento"
                  color="primary"
                  type="button"
                  (click)="handleClickVerArchivo($event,data.idEvento,data.documento)" >
            <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
      </lib-grid>
    </div>
  </lib-modal-container>
</ng-container>
```

typescript

```
descargartodo = (data) => {
    const { idEvento: idEvento } = this.store.selectSnapshot(FORM_RESUMEN_SOL_STATE_TOKEN); 
    this.solicitudesService.descargarSolAgendaWord(idEvento).subscribe(blob => {
      CORE_FUNCTIONS.downloadFile(blob, 'agenda.docx');
    })
    this.solicitudesService.descargarReporteInvitadosWord(idEvento).subscribe(blob => {
      CORE_FUNCTIONS.downloadFile(blob, 'invitados.docx');
    }); 
  }    
  handleClickVerArchivo = ($event, data, documento) => {
     const idEvento2 = data;
    if (documento == "Agenda") {
      try {
        this.solicitudesService.descargarSolAgendaWord(idEvento2).subscribe(blob => {
          CORE_FUNCTIONS.downloadFile(blob, 'agenda.docx');
        });
      } catch (e) { console.log("hubo un error") }
    }        
    }
```

**I need pass the values from handleClickVerArchivo to descargartodo**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
  <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<form novalidate #formIdToPass="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="handleClickVerArchivo(formIdToPass.value)">
    <label>ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="idToPass" ngModel>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<p>
{{ descargartodo() }}
</p>
```

ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  idToPass: number;
  constructor(){
    this.idToPass = 0;
  }

 descargartodo() {
  if (this.idToPass > 0 ){
   let data = this.idToPass
    console.log(this.idToPass)
    return data;
}}  

  
  handleClickVerArchivo(data) { 
    console.log(data)  
     this.idToPass = data.idToPass
  }
}
```

demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bdtydm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: hello and how would i call idtopass in descargartodo?

Comment: descargarTodo = (data) => {return data +1 };
newValue: number = this.descargarTodo(this.idToPass); // is this.idToPass = 3 // 4

Comment: :( this.idToPass return 0 in the console.log

Comment: I edit with a demo how this works in Stackblitz.

Comment: I just tested that it works only when I press the button descargartodo after the button handleClickVerArchivo because if I press the button descargartodo before it returns 0 how can I make the button handleClickVerArchivo return the value without pressing it?

Comment: Of course, because your question was pass this id from this method to the descargartodo. If you wanna the same data in both methods you can try to get the id like in (click)="handleClickVerArchivo($event,data...) in  (click)="descargartodo(data )"<--- but when you click this button you have access to this id?

Comment: no, data to descargartodo in html does not return anything I just have it by default there

Comment: So you get the list (with ids), then you can click to `descargatodo()`. you can refactor your code to get a better approach, handle this situation with some ngIf, block the button till you have idToPass, etc